# Foreign key django - Database Relationships

Tags: sql, django, foreign-keys

I have a model for the Product Perfume, the product have different volume and prices.
I need to render the volume and price for each but i get "'function' object has no attribute 'prices'"

Any ideas? iam grateful for any suggestions

**View:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView
from products.models import Perfume, Pricing



def getIndex(request):
    
    
    perfumes = Perfume.objects.all
    thePrice= perfumes.prices.all()
    
    
   

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'perfumes': perfumes, 'thePrice':thePrice})
```

**Model**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Perfume(models.Model):
  
    genderChoice = (
        ('unisex','unisex'), ('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female'))
         
   
         
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=genderChoice, default='unisex')
    

    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product_image')
    created = models.DateField()
    author =models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    show_for_consumer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name        


class Pricing(models.Model):
    product =models.ForeignKey(Perfume, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='prices')
    
     
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    volume= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
         return 'Perfume {} - Price{} - Volume {}'.format(self.product.name,self.price, self.volume)
```

Comment: Can you show us the template so we can see how you want to display the prices?

Comment: Iam not able to upload it here, some formating issues, i put it in line 115 https://github.com/Rawa08/bon/blob/django-dev/bon/templates_copy/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to correct the missing `()` in getting the perfumes queryset

```py
perfumes = Perfume.objects.all()
```

This `thePrice = perfumes.prices.all()` is incorrect. You have to do this for *every perfume*, not for a `queryset` of perfumes.

Since `Perfume` and `Pricing` have a one-to-many relationship, you can directly access the prices from every perfume instance. This way you only need to pass the perfumes `queryset`

```py
def getIndex(request):
    perfumes = Perfume.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'perfumes': perfumes})
```

Finally, in your template, you can call the prices like this

```html
{% for product in perfumes %}
  ...
  {% for p in product.prices.all %}
    <option>{{p.volume}}ml - {{p.price}}$ </option>
  ...
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome.